# Recording from Pulseaudio sink AND source at the same time

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, recording

I'm trying to record a Google Meet call I'm participating in (audio only). Creating a combined sink from a null sink and my headphones sink, redirecting browser to combined sink and recording null sink monitor fulfills the first part of that task:

```
pacmd load-module module-null-sink sink_name=recording sink_properties=device.description=recording
pacmd load-module module-combine-sink sink_name=combined sink_properties=device.description=combined \
  slaves=recording,alsa_output.usb-Sennheiser_Communications_Sennheiser_USB_headset-00.analog-stereo
```

Now I'm recording "theirs" side of call with

```
parecord --channels=1 -d recording.monitor recording.wav
```

Now the second part of the task is to record "my" side of call (the sound which is sourced from my microphone). Ideally I'd like to get the recording in a single file, putting sinked and sourced sound on different channels, but separate files will also do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working. The trick was to create a loopback and direct it to the recording sink:

```
pacmd load-module module-null-sink sink_name=Recording sink_properties=device.description=Recording
pacmd load-module module-combine-sink sink_name=Combined slaves=Recording,alsa_output.usb-Sennheiser_Communications_Sennheiser_USB_headset-00.analog-stereo sink_properties=device.description=Combined
pacmd load-module module-loopback source=alsa_input.usb-Sennheiser_Communications_Sennheiser_USB_headset-00.mono-fallback sink=Recording latency_msec=1
```

Now, application being recorded should be directed to use Combined sink through PulseAudio mixer. After that,

```
parecord --channels=2 -d Recording.monitor output.wav
```

Such way it records sourced and sunk audio to the same channel(s) of output wav.  I will experiment more with channel remapping to get sourced and sunk audio on separate channels but for now it's just enough.